# Should I use vh or vw for font-size?

Tags: html, css

I'm interested in using css's new vh/vw for different sized screens.

But I'm wondering if I should use vh or vw for font.

```
<div style='font-size:10vh'>This is a test</div>
```

or

```
<div style='font-size:10vw'>This is a test</div>
```

Really what I'd like is to use both. Kind of like the way you scale an image in photoshop.

NOTE: I tried using vmin, but it's not good either. The font-changes depending on window size. So sometimes it wraps, sometimes it doesn't. I'd like to find a way for it to scale. Just like you'd scale an image. For example when you scale an image in photoshop it wouldn't change the wrapping/location of the font. It'd just either make the font wider or taller, depending on the scale size (without constraints on proportion) That's what I'm looking for.

[image]

here's another (with the window slightly wider). Note: it's inside a box that is also using vh/vw for height/width.

[image]

Comment: it's better in general to use `em` if possible, but, if you must use viewport units, i'd use `vmin`, since it defaults to the smallest. So, if the window is wider than tall, `vmin` is equivalent to `vh`, if it's taller than wide it'll be the same as `vw`

Comment: em doesn't adjust to viewport size though.. so for example, when you're adjusting the size of the window the font doesn't change. I want it to scale.

Comment: Then, go with `vmin`. I just mentioned `em` because it's generally the best way to determine font size if you want it to adjust to user settings, but for you needs `vmin` will work I guess

Comment: So you basically want it to maintain a constant total width of the text?

Comment: no i want the width and height of my text to take into consideration the window size, both x and y. for example, say we have a .png file that says "hello world", and using a graphics program i can scale this image to whatever width/height i want and the text will stretch accordingly. that's how i want the css font-size to act. but it seems to not work that way unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

`vmin` is a viewport unit (although glitchy support in IE<=9: http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport) that automatically sets itself to the lesser of `vh` and `vw`. So, if the window is taller than it is wide, `vmin` acts as `vw`. If the window's wider than it is tall, `vmin` is `vh`

EDIT:

I see you didn't think it scales properly, but this example seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/dtvz5mty/ if you still don't like it try replacing `vmin` with `vw` in the example, and it works

Comment: thanks again, but this scales only in regards to width. hopefully you understood what I meant with the example I gave with scaling an image in a graphics program, that's the behavior i want. I basically want it to scale with respects to both vh and vw, together.  vh/vw/vmin/vmax simply does not support what i am looking for in regards to fonts. (in regards to divs it's fine because a div has two dimensions)

Comment: This will distort the text. Are you ok with that?